# Dynamic shell command to create single PDF file

Tags: vba, excel

I need a dynamic shell command with multiple paths to create a single PDF file with FreePDF join (Unfortunately I can't use another program).

My code creates first multiple single PDF files in the `TmpPath` and create than a single PDF file with the code below. After that the TmpFiles will be removed.

The process works without any problems but I think the code below is pretty bad and I need to repeat the same code for 100 cells to check if the cell is empty.

Code reduced - g(1 till 3)

Any ideas how can I can optimize and shrink this code?

```
   Dim g(100)
   NameA = "Test"
   PathA = ThisWorkbook.Path
   FileA = Chr(34) & PathA & NameA & " CW " & ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value & ".pdf" & Chr(34)

   If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 7).Value) Then
    g(1) = ""
Else
    g(1) = """" & GetTmpPath & NameA & " " & ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 7).Value & ".pdf" & """"
End If
If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 7).Value) Then
    g(2) = ""
Else
    g(2) = """" & GetTmpPath & NameA & " " & ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 7).Value & ".pdf" & """"
End If
If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 7).Value) Then
    g(3) = ""
Else
    g(3) = """" & GetTmpPath & NameA & " " & ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 7).Value & ".pdf" & """"
End If

For n = 1 To 6

Next

ShellWait FreePDF & " /m " _
                & FileA & "" _
                & "" & g(1) & " " & "" & g(2) & " " & "" & g(3) & " " & "" & g(4) & " " & "" & g(5) & " " & "" & g(6) & " " & "" & g(7) & " " & "" & g(8) & " " & "" & g(9) & " " & "" & g(10) & " " & "" & g(11) & " " & "" & g(12) & " " & "" & g(13) & " " & "" & g(14) & " " & "" & g(15) & " " & "" & g(16) & " " & "" & g(17) & " " & "" & g(18) & " " & "" & g(19) & " " & "" & g(20) _
                & " " & "" & g(21) & " " & "" & g(22) & " " & "" & g(23) & " " & "" & g(24) & " " & "" & g(25) & " " & "" & g(26) & " " & "" & g(27) & " " & "" & g(28) & " " & "" & g(29) & " " & "" & g(30) & " " & "" & g(31) & " " & "" & g(32) & " " & "" & g(33) & " " & "" & g(34) & " " & "" & g(35) & " " & "" & g(36) & " " & "" & g(37) & " " & "" & g(38) & " " & "" & g(39) & " " & "" & g(40) _
                & " " & "" & g(41) & " " & "" & g(42) & " " & "" & g(43) & " " & "" & g(44) & " " & "" & g(45) & " " & "" & g(46) & " " & "" & g(47) & " " & "" & g(48) & " " & "" & g(49) & " " & "" & g(50) & " " & "" & g(51) & " " & "" & g(52) & " " & "" & g(53) & " " & "" & g(54) & " " & "" & g(55) & " " & "" & g(56) & " " & "" & g(57) & " " & "" & g(58) & " " & "" & g(59) & " " & "" & g(60) _
                & " " & "" & g(61) & " " & "" & g(62) & " " & "" & g(63) & " " & "" & g(64) & " " & "" & g(65) & " " & "" & g(66) & " " & "" & g(67) & " " & "" & g(68) & " " & "" & g(69) & " " & "" & g(70) & " " & "" & g(71) & " " & "" & g(72) & " " & "" & g(73) & " " & "" & g(74) & " " & "" & g(75) & " " & "" & g(76) & " " & "" & g(77) & " " & "" & g(78) & " " & "" & g(79) & " " & "" & g(80) _
                & " " & "" & g(81) & " " & "" & g(82) & " " & "" & g(83) & " " & "" & g(84) & " " & "" & g(85) & " " & "" & g(86) & " " & "" & g(87) & " " & "" & g(88) & " " & "" & g(89) & " " & "" & g(90) & " " & "" & g(91) & " " & "" & g(92) & " " & "" & g(93) & " " & "" & g(94) & " " & "" & g(95) & " " & "" & g(96) & " " & "" & g(97) & " " & "" & g(98) & " " & "" & g(99) & " " _
                & "" & g(100) & "", vbNormalFocus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming yo doesn't need any empty values in your Array, I used an ArrayList to store the values and `Join` to create a space separated string of the values.

```
Dim FileA As String, NameA As String, PathA As String
Dim x As Long
Dim list As Object
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

NameA = "Test"
PathA = ThisWorkbook.Path
FileA = Chr(34) & PathA & NameA & " CW " & ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value & ".pdf" & Chr(34)

With ActiveSheet
    For x = 7 To 107
        If .Cells(x, 7) > Value <> "" Then
            list.Add """" & GetTmpPath & NameA & " " & .Cells(x, 7).Value & ".pdf" & """"
        End If
    Next
End With

ShellWait FreePDF & " /m " _
          & FileA & "" _
          & Join(list.ToArray, " "), vbNormalFocus
```